# TKinter - User input writing into a file

Tags: python, tkinter

So, I'm using TKinter with Python to try and take an input from the user and write that into a seperate file for use later, but I can't seem to get it to work. Having looked over other questions and adapting some parts of my code in accordance to their answers, I still can't get it to work.

Here's the full code:

```
import tkinter

def write_File (text_File):
    file = open("users.txt", "a")
    user_Input = str(file)
    file.write(user_Input).get()
    text_File.insert(INSERT, file.read())
    file.close()

screen = tkinter.Tk()


the_input = tkinter.Entry(screen)
the_input.grid(row=1, column=1)

button_Write = tkinter.Button(screen, text = "Send to file:", command = lambda: write_File(the_input)).grid(row=10, column=1)

screen.mainloop()
```

The Error I'm given in the console, after pressing the button, says:

```
    File "[file directory]", line 9, in write_File
    file.write(user_Input).get()
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Anyone able to offer any assistance?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow, this is a nice, concise and easy to understand question, a very good first question.

Comment: @JakeConkerton-Darby Thank You!

Comment: One small addendum I would add, that I ran into while answering this question, is that you should probably add details on the specific behaviour you are trying to achieve. In this case there was a little ambiguity as to what is to happen when writing to the file multiple times.

Comment: you mean `file.write( text_File.get() )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'm not entirely certain what resources you were using to create write_File, but there were a few errors. I've fixed them in the below code, with comments to explain what I've changed and why.

```
import tkinter

def write_File (text_File):
    file = open("users.txt", "a")
    #The object text_File is a tkinter.Entry object, so we will get
    #   the user input by calling the get method on that object.
    user_Input = text_File.get()
    #Here we now directly write the user input to the file that has been
    #   opened, I'm not sure you were previously doing with writing the
    #   string version of the file, but this appears to achieve what you
    #   desire.
    file.write(user_Input)
    file.close()

screen = tkinter.Tk()


the_input = tkinter.Entry(screen)
the_input.grid(row=1, column=1)

button_Write = tkinter.Button(screen, text = "Send to file:", command = lambda: write_File(the_input)).grid(row=10, column=1)

screen.mainloop()
```

Another thing is that depending on the version of Python you're using, instead of using `file = open(...)` and then `file.close()` at the end of the method, you could instead use the `with open(...) as file:` construct which will automatically close the file at the end of the scope.

Answer (score 1):

Your  function should look something like this:

```
def write_file (user_input):  # naming convention for functions in python is__like_this        
    file = open("users.txt", "a")  # 'a' stands for 'append'
    file.write(user_input)
    file.close()
```

or even better using [context manager](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/with-statement-in-python)

```
  def write_File (user_input):
      with open('users.txt', 'a') as file:
          file.write(user_input)
```

Comment: This is a nice concise version of my answer. I think it would benefit a little from adding some detail as to why you have made the changes you did, just to help others understand why your changes work.